# How to adjust similarity scores by removing the influence of a common vector?

Tags: correlation, linear-algebra, similarities, cosine-similarity

I have a similarity score function, $s(x,y)$. I know that I have two items that I'm trying to compare the similarity of, but both are based on the same template. How would I remove the template from the similarity?

In other words, I have $s(a,b)$, $s(a,T)$, and $s(b,T)$. I'm trying to find $s(A,B)$ where $a=a+T$ and $b=B+T$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if there is a common way to do this, despite different implementations of a similarity score. We can use cosine similarity, MOSS, etc. to imagine how the similarity score may be implemented.

Comment: I'm unsure if the tags are appropriate for this question. I am new to stats.SE - please suggest changes if certain tags are not appropriate for the question.